# How to display tld value from the json given below

Tags: php, laravel

From the below json I need to display the values of tld i.e., co.uk, eu,  live, org...

```
Array ( [tldlist] => Array ( [tld] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [tld] => co.uk ) [1] => Array ( [tld] => eu ) [2] => Array ( [tld] => live ) [3] => Array ( [tld] => org ) [4] => Array ( [tld] => Array ( ) ) ) [tldcount] => 5 ) [Command] => GETTLDLIST [APIType] => API [Language] => eng [ErrCount] => 0 [ResponseCount] => 0 [MinPeriod] => Array ( ) [MaxPeriod] => 10 [Server] => SJL1VWRESELL_T [Site] => eNom [IsLockable] => Array ( ) [IsRealTimeTLD] => Array ( ) [TimeDifference] => +0.00 [ExecTime] => 0.000 [Done] => true [TrackingKey] => 7cbc3d47-c11c-4a39-8387-448777e82af5 [RequestDateTime] => 5/14/2018 12:21:18 AM [debug] => Array ( ) ) 1
```

find below my blade code:

```
 @foreach($final_data1['tldlist']['tld'] as $key)

    {{$key}}<br>

 @endforeach
```

Please suggest me corrections in my blade file to display the tld from the above json.

Comment: Try `{{ $key['tld'] }}<br>`

Comment: when I use this I'm getting error as "Undefined index: tldlist"

Answer (score 0):

Preliminary note: the "json" you're showing isn't JSON, it's the output of `print_r()`.

---

Since JSON is just a string, you need to decode it first. The [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) states:

> **Function**
>
> json_decode ( string $json [, bool $assoc = FALSE [, int $depth = 512 [, int $options = 0 ]]] )
>
> **Parameters**
>
> *$json*
>   The json string being decoded.
>
> *$assoc*
>   When TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.

So associative arrays will be accessible as **an object** after decoding:

```
$data = json_decode($json);
$tld = $data->tldlist;
```

If you want it to be decoded as **an array**, pass `true` as the second parameter:

```
$data = json_decode($json, true);
$tld = $data['tldlist'];
```

I would advise to decode it in the controller. This way your view doesn't need to be concerned about how the data is passed.

Assuming you have a JSON string and want to access it as an array:

```
return view('your_blade_view')->with('final_data1', json_decode($data, true));
```

If you insist on doing this in your Blade file, use the following snippet:

```
@foreach($final_data1['tldlist']['tld'] as $key)

    {{$key}}<br>

@endforeach
```